# Is it possible to use Outlook web-addins as an object in a VBA macro?

Tags: excel, vba, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, excel-addins

I created a macro in Excel to create and display a new email with the BCC, Subject, and Body fields filled with data from specific cells in the Excel worksheet.

I have a plugin called "Smart Email" added to Outlook that keeps track of open rates and click rates of the "smart emails".

I'd like the VBA macro to create a "smart email" not a regular email.

How would I look up the object name of a addin or plugin in Outlook?
For example, is there a smart email (the add-in) object that I could swap in for the standard new Outlook email line `emailApplication.createitem(0)`?
Or, do only default Microsoft items show in the object library?

```vb
Sub CreateEmail()

'Set the variables:
Dim emailApplication As Object
Dim emailItem As Object

Set emailApplication = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set emailItem = emailApplication.createitem(0)

'To build the email. The body text, email addresses and subject line are saved in the excel cells listed below:
With emailItem
    .Body = Range("D17")
    .BCC = Range("D15")
    .Subject = Range("D16")
    .Display
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any API for communicating between VBA macros and web add-ins. But you may communicate with COM add-ins in Office applications using the [COMAddIns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.comaddins) property which returns a `COMAddIns` collection that represents all the Component Object Model (COM) add-ins currently loaded in Microsoft Outlook. See [Walkthrough: Call code in a VSTO Add-in from VBA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-calling-code-in-a-vsto-add-in-from-vba?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp) for more information.

The best what you could do is to programmatically click the ribbon controls or any other UI using [Accessibility API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/microsoft-active-accessibility) (Windows API). There is no trivial solution for that.

Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when the dev team go through the planning process. Use the github label: `Type: product feature request` at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .

Comment: Confirming Eugene's answer here. In general mixing COM Add-ins with Web Add-ins is not supported. There are certainly places where they interact. (i.e. the are reading from the same properties, or if you create a new mail with COM, it will trigger a OnNewMessage Web LaunchEvent) However, the features are not intended to be used together.